# Desabilitar button via php/jquery/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Saudações!
 Tenho uma página na qual contém um campo de 'pesquisa', ao digitar alguma coisa, o campo me retorna nomes similares.

Exemplo: Caso eu digite "a" ele me retorna "amador, amante, amarildo, amoxilina, atendente, alocar.." e etc.

E existe um button na index.php que serve pra enviar tais requisições
A questão é, caso eu digite "-" no campo, não vai me retornar nada, pois não existe tal valor no banco de dados, porém, ainda sim consigo enviar as requisições(que seria só pra salvar os nomes que aparecem em uma pagina), nesse caso, como não existe o nome similar a "-", ele envia a requisição, preenchendo um campo da pagina com um valor nulo(em branco).

Eu queria de alguma forma impedir que fosse possível enviar as requisições caso não haja tal valor dentro do banco de dados, uma forma que pensei foi:

Esse é o código do button, que me permite enviar a requisição

```
<button> Enviar<i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

Caso eu consiga verificar o campo de envio, se estiver incorreto, poderia desabilitar o button de tal forma

```
<button disabled=""> Enviar<i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

Há alguma forma de fazer essa mudança do código html via php? ou algum método melhor pra tratar tal operação..?

Obs: Esse é o único button existente na página, sendo assim, não seria um button em específico(por que se usar um código especificando a troca do status do button certamente desabilitaria todos da pagina)

**Edit1:** 
O "index.php" faz a conexão com o banco de dados e trata o mesmo fazendo o select para o campo de pesquisa de tal forma:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM bancod WHERE id like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,9";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$count=  mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count < 1){
        echo "Esse valor não existe no banco de dados ";
    }
```

Sendo assim ele já verifica a existência do valor digitado, se contém ou não no banco de dados. Caso não exista, ele me imprime "Esse valor não existe no banco de dados". Porém, ainda sim consigo enviar a solicitação clicando no button, porém como eu disse, ele preenche os campos de forma nula, todos em branco ): e eu queria só impedir que fosse possível enviar isso

Comment: "_Eu queria de alguma forma impedir que fosse possível enviar as requisições caso não haja tal valor dentro do banco de dados_"... como vc vai saber que não há um valor no banco de dados sem fazer uma requisição?

Comment: @Sam Editei o tópico, o "Edit1:" responde a pergunta

Comment: A única coisa que consigo pensar, pelo que entendi, é desabilitar o botão se o campo input estiver vazio ou criar algum critério no frontend. Por exemplo, verificar se o campo contém somente letras etc...

Comment: Essa seria uma boa, até pensei nisso, mas sendo mais direto, o campo só vai possuir pesquisas numéricas, exemplo: "20200200013" <= esse valor existe no BD, caso eu digite "20200200014", ele me imprime a mensagem "Esse valor não existe no banco de dados", porém se eu clicar em "Enviar"(button) ele envia, mesmo que o número informado não exista no BD e faz o preenchimento de uma tabela com tudo em branco(valores nulos)

Comment: Se não existir no BD, basta esvaziar o input e desabilitar o botão.

Answer (score 0):

Deve ter uma solução melhor mas isso pode funcionar

Na sua query:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM bancod WHERE id like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,9";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$count=  mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count < 1){
    $btn_disabled = 'disabled';
}else $btn_disabled = '';
```

E no botão:

```
<button <?=$btn_disabled ?> > Enviar<i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço de várias formas. 
Você pode fazer via PHP, se você já retornar o resultado do SELECT e perceber que o valor está correto, vc já consegue colocar o disabled no botão

Exemplo em PHP: 
Retorne o valor na variavel criada no php.

```
<?php if($valor != null or $valor != 0){
   $variavel_disabled = 'disabled';
}else{
  $variavel_disabled = '';
}?>

<button <?php echo $variavel_disabled ?> >Enviar<i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

Ou, se você for enviar do html via javascript e vai retornar por ele, você pode também desabilitar pelo javascript.

```
var btn = $('.zmdi');
btn.attr('disabled', true);
```

há varias formas de fazer, veja qual se encaixa melhor.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de fazer isso seria mesmo com Ajax, OO e talvez o uso de PDO, mas do jeito que está a minha sugestão é bem parecida com a do Lucas, só mudaria a query.

```
$query ="SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM bancod WHERE id like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if($result['total'] < 1){
```

Desse jeito o consumo do banco seria menor e você só traria d banco de dados informações que você iria usar.